# Formatting time using the current user's format settings in Dynamics CRM

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2015

I've a control in an SSRS report which shows date time values and am trying to format it using the current user's format settings for time (User could set it to HH:mm or hh:mm tt).

I'm using Dynamics CRM built-in parameter CRM_ShortTimePattern to do that. But that does not seem to work. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You are passing `CRM_ShortTimePattern` as a report parameter and using it in the report? If yes, where and which expression are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the value from the UserSettings table via a filtered view is much more reliable than the built-in CRM parameters like CRM_ShortTimePattern or CRM_FormatTime. I used the following query to get the current user's time format:

```
select [TimeFormatString] from [FilteredUserSettings] where [SystemUserId] = dbo.fn_FindUserGuid()
```